# How do I use ffmpeg in Andriod Studio? I am getting a corrupt file

Tags: android, android-studio, ffmpeg

I am trying to use this ffmpeg library in Android Studio.

https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

The execution I want to do is converting 3gp saved in storage to wav file like this.

```
int rc = FFmpeg.execute("-i file1.3gp file2.wav");
```

in my own code, I replace files with my file path like this.

```
int rc = FFmpeg.execute("-i /storage/emulated/0/AudioRecording.3gp /storage/emulated/0/AudioRecording.wav");
```

When I try to do this, I get an execution error. Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
I was changing intent before the execution was done.